# I am getting a segmentation fault while creating a program of multiplication table

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    z=x*y;

    10<x<20,y<10;

    x=rand()%20;
    y=rand()%10;
    printf("%2d",x);
    printf("%2d",y);
    printf("enter value of z");
    scanf("%d",z);

    if(z=x*y)
    {
       printf("correct");
    }
    else
      printf("wrong no. entered");
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault error, please help.

Comment: There are some problems other than the segmentation fault...

Comment: You seem to have some random, pointless lines at the beginning of your source.  Also, your indentation is poor, (ie. missing), which makes your source hard to read and follow:(

Comment: Repeating text to avoid an SO limitation is unfriendly:(

Comment: @sg7 Thank you, I was about to do that.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The segmentation fault is because you are calling `scanf()` with the `z` value instead of a pointer to it.

When `scanf()` encounters a `"%d"` specifier it expects a pointer to `int` to store the resulting value there, you passed an `int` instead and one that is not even initialized, so `scanf()` will dereference a pointer that doesn't point to valid memory thus causing a *SEGMENTATION FAULT*.

But that's not the only problem with your code, in fact there are many for such little code:

1. The signature of `main()` MUST be one of the following

   - `int main(void)`
   - `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or the equivalent `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
2. Your code is really bad formatted, and even if that's not a reason for it to behave worng it's a reason to worry about.
3. You used `x` and `y` without first initializing them, that's *undefined behavior*.
4. This statement

   ```
   10 < x < 20 , y < 10;
   ```

   does ABSOLUTELY NOTHING.
5. You didn't include *stdlib.h* needed for `rand()`'s prototype.
6. You did what you did with `scanf()` explained above.
7. `if (z = x * y)` will simply assign to `x * y` to `z` and unless `x` or `y` is *0* (*zero*) evaluate to true.

   The comparison operator in [c](/questions/tagged/c) is `==`.

Your code should look more like the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int x, y, z;

    x = rand() % 20;
    y = rand() % 10;

    printf("%2d", x);
    printf("%2d", y);

    printf("enter value of z ");
    if (scanf("%d", &z) == 1) {
        if (z == x * y) {
            printf("correct\n");
        } else {
            printf("error\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what should be done?

Comment: That's not all there is wrong with the code!

Comment: @WeatherVane No, of course. It was a lot, it took time to write it.

Comment: Both of `z = x * y` look strange. The first one is multiplying uninitialized valuables. The second one may be used with comparision desired.

Comment: what else is wrong?

Comment: @Dev Not sure, let me read it again ... terrible code. I didn't see the `if  (z = x * y)` and well assumed that it would be correct.

Comment: @Dev I think it's fine now, little code with too many mistakes. In spanish somtimes there are words written with multiple spelling mistakes like "*avitasion*" has 4 mistakes it should be "*habitación*", so this code is similar to that. I don't know if you can do the same in english, and in spanish there are people who actually write like that.